# Can't update user.photo in Carrierwave Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave, cloudinary

I'm trying to update the user.photo with a cloudinary upload response.

When I do it in the console the update works without any errors but the user isn't actually updated.

This is my code:

```
  @user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
  img = Cloudinary::Uploader.upload(params[:image])
  @user.photo = img
```

This doesn't throw any error but it doesn't update the user with the appropriate photo.

I have a user model like so that works fine with my form but the updating through the API with the code above doesn't work for some reason.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader
end
```

In the console, when I do:

```
user.photo = photo
```

I get the following response:

```
{"public_id"=>"shyq5kcnwpcff9dpxk0c",
...
 "width"=>1239,
 "height"=>825,
 "format"=>"jpg",
 "resource_type"=>"image",
 "created_at"=>"2018-01-07T19:16:50Z",
 "tags"=>[],
 "bytes"=>54341,
 "type"=>"upload",
 "etag"=>"c0716df24b6e8cd639611d3259ec8b76",
 "placeholder"=>false,
 "url"=>"http://res.cloudinary.com/dmcobwlzr/image/upload/v1515352610/shyq5kcnwpcff9dpxk0c.jpg",
 "secure_url"=>"https://res.cloudinary.com/dmcobwlzr/image/upload/v1515352610/shyq5kcnwpcff9dpxk0c.jpg",
 "original_filename"=>"1515352508510",
 "original_extension"=>"png"}
```

Lastly, user.save doesn't actualy do anything, without throwing any error.

Comment: call `save` -))

Comment: @marmeladze save doesnt actualy do anything.

Comment: the only way to do it was to use remote_photo_url but not sure what it does

Comment: I can not really dig deep into this because I don't understand the reason of doing it. I just use carrierwave with AWS, if the user wants to change the picture then he update his profile with the `registrations#edit` action and it just works. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio that's because I have a react native mobile app using my rails api and I have to update the user profile with a image file coming from Api but I want to keep the user model the same structure as the user model in my rails web app...

Comment: It is not a good apprach. `Ruby on Rails` uses `turbolinks-android` and `turbolinks-ios` to deploy mobile apps and there is no need to build a backend api. https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-ios https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-android  https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks We need to follow `DHH` strategy https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SWEts0rlezA&t=233s

Comment: thiose are code pieces from my working cloudinary-rails-carrierwave app. https://gist.github.com/marmeladze/f8c791a9b073b13519ce7a87704da350